# Is it possible to filter countries in my eBay searches?

Tags: ebay

For example, I would like to order from a certain country or countries, that I know can ship to my country but I do not want all other countries which makes the search more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should be able to select a specific country but for more than one may have to repeat searches. In Advanced search, reachable for me via a Google Search for `ebay`:

[image: WA45949 first example]

Here for the US site: `https://www.ebay.com/sch/ebayadvsearch`, go to Location and choose:

[image: WA45949 second example]

Comment: What's up with "North America" showing twice?